# AngularJS sorting by field value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

What I am trying to do is sort some data by field value.

```
$scope.testarr = [{"id":"1","name":"coffee"},
                  {"id":"2","name":"tea"},
                  {"id":"3","name":"coffee"},
                  {"id":"4","name":"ice coffee"}]
```

in the html file i have select box and 3 options called  **coffee**, **tea** and **ice coffee**,

if i select coffee should be sorted like this

```
   $scope.testarr = [{"id":"1","name":"coffee"},
                      {"id":"3","name":"coffee"},
                      {"id":"2","name":"tea"},
                      {"id":"4","name":"ice coffee"}]
```

if i select tea should be sorted like this

```
   $scope.testarr = [
                      {"id":"2","name":"tea"},
                      {"id":"1","name":"coffee"},
                      {"id":"3","name":"coffee"},
                      {"id":"4","name":"ice coffee"}]
```

i'm trying to use order by but somehow it does't work

```
<div ng-repeat="item in testarr | orderBy: 'name'">
     {{item.id}} ------ {{item.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: Does the console show any error?

Comment: no errors. it does't sort the way i wanted

Comment: I guess you wanted to sort the name alphabetically..
Have you tried to use another parameter for sorting the list?

Comment: So, if you select "coffee", all the elements having the name "coffee" should come first, and the other ones should stay in the same order, is that right? I wouldn't use orderBy to do that. I would use ng-change, and rearrange the array by myself. Your code can't possibly work, since the value passed to orderBy is always the same, whatever the selection is.

Comment: yep thats exactly what i want JB Nizet. is there any way i can do this without rearranging the array

Comment: Nope, I would rather create a function that handles the name the user has chosen and returns true if the name is a substring (the initial string in particular)  of a generic string... Then you use that function is a condition as ng-show for each item of the list

Comment: @LucaMarzi that would be a filter. But the OP doesn't want to filter out items. Unless of course you use two loops, one displaying the accepted elements only, then one displaying the rejected elements only. But I'd rather do that in JavaScript code, and create a new array containing the elements in the right order.

Comment: thanks @LucaMarzi i will try that

Comment: @JBNizet ok so you can use the function as a orderBy value as well.  This way, if you sort  decreasing values you get the elements with the "coffee" substring first.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem to work. Ensure that your `ng-repeat` has access to `$scope.testarr` (i.e. it is being declared on your `$scope` in the correct controller or directive.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.testarr = [{
      "id": "1",
      "name": "coffee"
    }, {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "tea"
    }, {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "coffee"
    }, {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "ice coffee"
    }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in testarr | orderBy: 'name'">
      {{item.id}} ------ {{item.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```